# How cassandra handles updates with-in memtable

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

During compaction, if we have two or more versions of the same row, Cassandra only writes the most recent version to the new SSTable.
During the read process, if a row has multiple versions on SSTables, a comparison is done.

1.Does the same thing happen when the row is in memtable only (not yet flushed)?
2.How does Cassandra handle multiple updates to a row which is not yet flushed to SSTable. 
3.Does reading a record (with multiple versions) from memtable vs SSTables have any effect on performance?
4.I have a scenario of application updating a row frequently (10 times) only during the first 5 mins of its entry. This is likely to happen when the row is in memtable (not yet flushed). What would be the preferred way to handle this?

Sorry for multiple questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Only the last update is kept in memory
3. in-memory is always faster than on-disk
4. don't expect memtable to keep multiple changes in memory.

Comment: Well, there are actually `duplicates` in memory, just with different timestamp https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlWriteUpdate.html

Answer (score 0):

To get your answer you need to understand how Cassandra read and writes data. Read through this link to find details.[How Cassandra reads and writes data](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlIntro.html)

> 1.Does the same thing happen when the row is in memtable only (not yet flushed)?

***No. It replaces existing values on updating the same key.***

> 2.How does Cassandra handle multiple updates to a row which is not yet flushed to SSTable.

`When a write occurs, Cassandra stores the data in a memory structure called memtable, and to provide configurable durability, it also appends writes to the commit log on disk. The commit log receives every write made to a Cassandra node, and these durable writes survive permanently even if power fails on a node. The memtable is a write-back cache of data partitions that Cassandra looks up by key. The memtable stores writes in sorted order until reaching a configurable limit, and then is flushed.`

> 3.Does reading a record (with multiple versions) from memtable vs SSTables have any effect on performance?

***It is obvious that memtable access is way-more faster than multiple version sstable accesses***

> 4.I have a scenario of application updating a row frequently (10 times) only during the first 5 mins of its entry. This is likely to happen when the row is in memtable (not yet flushed). What would be the preferred way to handle this?

It would be better if you enable **row cache**. Also you can increase `memtable` and `commit log` size to get the optimal performance.

Links: [Configuring data caches](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/latest/cassandra/operations/opsConfiguringCaches.html)